# Is $\operatorname{Var}(\varphi(X)) \leq \operatorname{Var}(X)$ for "shrinking" functions $\varphi$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a positive random variable and $\varphi$ a positive nondecreasing concave function with $\varphi(x) \leq x$ (e.g. $\varphi(x) = \sqrt{x}$). Is it true that $$\operatorname{Va}r(\varphi(X)) \leq \operatorname{Var}(X)?$$

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ doesn't shrink on $(0,\,1)$.

Comment: Ah, you are right. So, when we take a random variable $X$ on $[0,1]$ the conjecture should be falsifiable.